# How to get rid of: "Package hyperref Warning: The PDF version number could not be set because some PDF objects are already written"?

Tags: hyperref, luatex, pdfx

I want to use the pdfx package with LuaLatex to generate a PDF/X compliant PDF file.

The following Warning outputs:

```
Package hyperref Warning: The PDF version number could not be set,                                                                                                                                                                            
(hyperref)                because some PDF objects are already written:                                                                                                                                                                       
(hyperref)                  3 PDF objects                                                                                                                                                                                                     
(hyperref)                The version should be set as early as possible:                                                                                                                                                                     
(hyperref)                  =1, =4\relax                                                                                                                                                                                                    
(hyperref)                  \pdfobjcompresslevel=0\relax.                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Package hyperref Info: .:=1.4 on input line 240.
```

How can I get rid of it?

Here's a MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.xmpdata}
  \Title{Sacrat\'issimum}
  \Author{M.}
  \Language{es}
  \Keywords{Rosa}
  \Publisher{}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[b6paper, 10pt, twoside, openright, final]{memoir}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1.25cm}{.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{1.5cm}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout{}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[spanish,es-ucroman]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{gregoriotex}

\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[x-1a1]{pdfx}
\hypersetup{final}
\usepackage[stamp=true]{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkText{BORRADOR}
\SetWatermarkScale{1}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand\blankpage {
  \addtocounter{page}{-1}
  \newpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  Esta p\'agina ha sido dejada en blanco intencionalmente.
  \newpage
}

\begin{document}
  \frontmatter
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \title{
    \HUGE
    Sacrat\'issimum
  }
  \author{M}
  \date{8 de diciembre de 2022}
  \begin{center}
    \maketitle
    Solemnidad 
    \vspace{\fill}
    TRIA
  \end{center}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add an compilable short TeX code to the question ...

Comment: @Mensch Hi, I put some code in the following link: https://termbin.com/jcs9y.  Does it works?

Comment: @daleif, Thanks for the clarification.  I included a short snippet...

Answer (score 1):

The `x-1a1` standard is for PDF 1.3 (do you really want that??) and so
pdfx tries to set this and uses hyperref for it.

The problem is that `hyperref` should on one side be loaded late, as it wants to patch various code, on the other side to set the PDF version it must be loaded early, as it can only set it as long no other package has written something to the PDF.

The best when using pdfx is imho to set the required pdf version independently at the begin and to ignore the warning:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\sys_ensure_backend:
\pdf_version_gset:n{1.3}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\documentclass{...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for taking a look at it.

I loaded the pdfx package at a different order and the warning went away.

Here's an excerpt of the change I did:

```
\usepackage[x-1a1]{pdfx}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{url}
```

Comment: if you move pdfx will probably get a pdf 1.4 which is wrong. Check it better.